# Availability of diff in edit view

Tags: feature-request, edits

When I try to do an edit I really miss a possibility to see the difference between original and edited question/answer. Especially when I try to improve formatting of source code. The possibility to see diff by editor would mean less rejected/incorrect edits, because editor could catch his errors before review process.

Comment: Does the "preview" not help you in achiving that goal -- i.e. seeing what you edits looks like before saving?

Comment: @Soren this is a suggestion from a user that fills the review queue... personally I do not need that to improve posts, but I didn't have that much rejected suggested edits...

Comment: I would also like this. When fighting with markdown (especially when dealing with source code formatting as OP said) it's easy to introduce unwanted changes. @Soren the preview is helpful obviously, but no, it's not a substitute for a diff.